# MySQL Self-Join to combine table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am thinking to cartesian product of SETS from the data I got from one table.
Let's say I have

```
Table A
No    | Name         | Sequence
1.    | SET A        | 1
2.    | SET B        | 2
3.    | SET C        | 3

Table B
No    | Name         | Data
1.    | SET A        | 01
2.    | SET A        | 02
3.    | SET B        | 01    
4.    | SET B        | 02
5.    | SET C        | 01
6.    | SET C        | 02
```

The result I want is based on a cartesian product of SETS
Let's say

```
Table AB
No    | Name             | Data       | Data       | Data
1.    | SET AxBxC        | 01         | 01         | 01
2.    | SET AxBxC        | 01         | 01         | 02
3.    | SET AxBxC        | 01         | 02         | 01
4.    | SET AxBxC        | 01         | 02         | 02
5.    | SET AxBxC        | 02         | 01         | 01
6.    | SET AxBxC        | 02         | 01         | 02
7.    | SET AxBxC        | 02         | 02         | 01
8.    | SET AxBxC        | 02         | 02         | 02
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want in the 2nd ,3rd,4th ,5th in your result table?

Comment: basically what i need is a cartesian product of rows based on Table B. But sequence is defined in Table A (A * B * C)